# Do I need FTP set up to upload files to wordpress server

Tags: uploads, ftp

Does FTP need to be set up on a server hosting my wordpress site. I am unable to upload files and there are still many things to check, but I need a straight answer to this before I waste too much time.

All I have done to get this site up and running is copy the document root from my localhost to a remote server. There is no FTP or cpanel set up on that server. I am unable to upload files from the wordpress admin interface. Do I need to setup FTP in order to upload these files?

Comment: No, you can SSH for example. As long as the files have the right permissions and get to the right place, the way you transfer them is trivial.

Comment: @elclanrs SSH is setup for this server, so I should be able to upload files from the browser interface?

Comment: What stack are you using? In LAMP just copy it over: `scp -r wordpress/* user@domain.com:/var/www/wordpress/`. Adjust to your needs. Then make sure that when you move the DB from your localhost you replace all instances of `localhost` with your domain name, and it should work.

Comment: SSH can't be used to upload files from a browser. However, if SFTP is setup, you can. Alternatively, you may use a similar solution such as [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org).